# How to round a big number to 1000 position in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to round a big numer like 15698 to the lowest, nearest 1000-th value like this:

```
num = 15698
num_round = function(num)

>> num_round = 15000
```

How can I do this? I only found `np.round` where I can set the decimals but haven't found a similar function for my case.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You actually can use np.round for similar tasks. `np.round(num, -3)` will round to nearest thousand and give you 16000. To get your desired effect of getting the lower near thousand, you can do `np.round(num-1000//2, -3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def round(num, factor=1000):
    return (num//factor)*factor
```